2 colums in a child table have foriegn key relation with same parent table how to delete them using cascade in spring boot domain class
//Parent class
Class parent
{
    String id;
     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent1", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<child> groupMembers = new HashSet<>(0);

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent2", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<child> groupMembers1 = new HashSet<>(0);
}

//clild class

class child
{
       String id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent1")
  private parent parent1;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent2")
  private parent parent2;
}
//While deleting one of the parent object in sprint boot using
parentRepository.delete(id); it still says ERROR: update or delete on table "parent" violates foreign key constraint "child_parent2_fkey" on table "child"

Tried deleting with separate deletion queries individually on child class and it worked.
using cascade its not working
